# My PCs are connected to a router switch and my NAS is connected to the router. Would I be able to access my Nas from the computer connected to switch

Tags: database, switch-statement, router, nas, hub

See the diagram on my connection is a follow-

```
                |-Pc 1
       |-Switch-|-Pc 2
       |        |-Pc 3
Router-|-Other Devices connected to the router with wifi.
       |
       |-NAS
```

Here I can access the NAS from the router with SMB.
But my question is will I able to use NAS SMB with the switch connected to the router.
This means would I be able to connect with my pcs with the nas?
If Yes then please give example how to do this and take the name of NAS as idmakerNAS.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A switch is not a router, it doesn't have it's own IP subnet. All your PCs will have the same subnet which the router gives you. So there's basically no difference.

Yes you will be able to access the NAS from your PCs.